# Converting List to Array Repeatedly Results in Occasional Slowdown

Tags: f#

I wanted to see if there was any performance difference between List.toArray and Seq.toArray so I wrote a little script. I run the various tests a number of times. I compiled this on **Release** mode.

```
open System.Diagnostics

let n = 5000000

let biglist = [1.0 .. float(n)]

let SeqTest input = 
    input |> Seq.toArray

let ListTest input = 
    input |> List.toArray

let timeIt (name : string) (f : float list -> 'T) : unit =
    let sw = Stopwatch ()
    sw.Start ()
    f biglist |> ignore
    let d = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
    printfn "%s, elapsed %d ms" name d

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    timeIt "SeqTest" SeqTest
    timeIt "ListTest" ListTest 

    timeIt "ListTest" ListTest  
    timeIt "SeqTest" SeqTest

    timeIt "SeqTest" SeqTest
    timeIt "ListTest" ListTest

    timeIt "ListTest" ListTest 
    timeIt "SeqTest" SeqTest

    timeIt "SeqTest" SeqTest
    timeIt "ListTest" ListTest 
    0
```

This was what I got when I ran the program:

```
ListTest, elapsed 27 ms
SeqTest, elapsed 26 ms
SeqTest, elapsed 136 ms
ListTest, elapsed 27 ms
ListTest, elapsed 135 ms
SeqTest, elapsed 26 ms
SeqTest, elapsed 136 ms
ListTest, elapsed 26 ms
ListTest, elapsed 138 ms
SeqTest, elapsed 29 ms
```

I noticed that the 3rd test takes longer than the previous 2 tests and that after that 3rd test every other test takes similarly long to run. Why does this happen?

Edit: The comment from Gilles seem to indicate that this is because of garbage collection. Is there any way for me to show this?

Comment: GC is the first thing that comes to mind. Try adding GC traces in your test (I have no idea how to do this in F#).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @Gilles, I was able to determine that it was the garbage collector slowing me down. When I force the garbage collector to run with `System.GC.Collect()` after each timing test, my test results gave consistent times.

Comment: You could also (in addition) experiment with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.trystartnogcregion.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.endnogcregion.aspx (available in .NET 4.6) Using these you can ensure that there is no GC overhead occurring during timing. Obviously you should also profile production code including GC.